# twitter4j - unrecognized ssl message, plaintext connection?

Tags: ssl, twitter4j

I'm trying to connect to Twitter through the twitter4j library. However, I get the following exception:

```
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=506c3b98 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1136696a
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[506c3b98-1136696a 63e3f388-1596bf9d],           statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1786)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:255)
at edu.ihu.SearchTweets.main(SearchTweets.java:24)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I checked internet connection settings in Eclipse (the IDE I'm using for development). The HTTPS port is set correctly and I can access Twitter through the internal web browser of Eclipse. Any suggestion to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your code with the connection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648772/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection)

Comment: I resolved this problem. It was related to my firewall settings