# Open connection failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: java, ssl

I have created a a rest mockservice using SOAP UI.
    And I am trying to connect it from my java class. But It is failing with error

```
Open connection failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Below is the code -

```
java.net.URL url = new URL(null, address,new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
connection = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

And The URL I am trying to connect is - http://localhost:8089

Comment: You are mixing HTTP and HTTPS stuff. Is the mock service exposed through SSL by SOAP UI? You just need to change the address variable  scheme to HTTPS. Is SOAP UI exposing the mock through HTTP? You have to use URLConnection instead of HttpsURLConnection

Comment: No my mockservice is not exposed through SSL , How can I don that ? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use **HTTPS** then

> The HTTPS (HTTP over SSL) protocol handler has its own set of
>   properties:
>
> ```
> https.proxyHost
> https.proxyPort
> ```
>
> As you probably guessed these work in the exact same manner as their
>   http counterparts, so we won't go into much detail except to mention
>   that the default port number, this time, is 443 and that for the "non
>   proxy hosts" list, the HTTPS protocol handler will use the same as the
>   http handler (i.e. http.nonProxyHosts).

### Resource Link:

[Java Networking and Proxies for HTTPS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

### Solution-1:

Add the following to the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable:

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

**Restart** your Crowd instance.

### Resource Link:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowdkb/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-582877397.html

### Solution-2:

I think this is due to the connection established with the client machine is not secure.
It is due to the fact that you are talking to an HTTP server, not an HTTPS server. Probably you didn't use the correct port number for HTTPS.

Credit goes to @[EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp)

### Resource Link:

[Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception)

### Solution-3:

If you use SMTP domain name, then `mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback` properites need to be true.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true"); // Make it true
```

You can go through this link also: [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648772/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection)

Comment: Solution 3 ended up working for me.

Comment: I think this is due to the connection established with the client machine is not secure.

It is due to the fact that you are talking to an HTTP server, not an HTTPS server. Probably you didn't use the correct port number for HTTPS.

Answer (score -2):

```
java.net.URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8089");
java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

Comment: This will work as a http request but I want to make it as https.

Comment: @SUNNY Then use correct port number

Comment: Don't simply post a code snippet, add some clarifications to your answer. Answers like this one are often deleted.